# Recalling a Method [ What Am I Doing Wrong? ]

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a program which takes two integers i input, and returns the bigger of the two.  So it would function like this when I type it in Terminal

java Assign5 23 67

the bigger value of the two is 67

So far this is what I have

```
//Main Method  

public class asign5 {
public static void main (String[] args){
    int num1;
    int num2;      
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

System.out.println("The larger value of the two is: " + getMax(num1, num2));

}
}


//getMax Method  


public static int getMax(num1, num2){

if (num1 > num2) { return num1; } 
else
{return num2;}

}

}
```

It keeps telling me in my main method that getMax is not a valid method although I have created the getMax method. In the getMax method it keeps telling me that public static int is synthax. I've actually spent the last two hours on this roadblock, but have not figured out myself and it's frustrating my brains out. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You've closed the `asign5` class declaration after `main`, so the `getMax` method isn't actually in a class at the moment - just remove the second closing brace from before the `getMax` method. If you had appropriate indentation, this should be obvious: I'd recommend using either an IDE or a text editor which is Java-aware so that you can see this sort of thing very easily.

You also need to change the `getMax` method signature to specify types for `num1` and `num2`:

```
public static int getMax(int num1, int num2)
```

Comment: I do use Eclipse. As for the method, for what I inputed in my code, it keeps declaring Syntax error on token int.

Comment: @Kevin: If you use Eclipse, then I'd expect the indentation to make it obvious what's wrong. If it's not, try reformatting the whole file. Have you done what I suggested and removed the second closing brace before `getMax`?